# On the mere definition of divergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition, divergent-series

If we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$
we say that as x tends towards infinity $f(x)$ *diverges*.

For what reason do we **not** say

as x tends towards infinity $f(x)$ *converges* to $\infty$?

Comment: Many do say that.  But some argue that we should not say it, because to converge means to get arbitrarily close but a finite number can never get arbitrarily close to infinity.  It doesn't really matter what we say in this context, as long as we're clear on the rigorous definitions of what these things mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* say that it converges in the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), sometimes denoted $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. However, usually in the context of the ordinary real numbers we do not say that it converges simply because $\infty$ is not a real number.